# Check Box -> Show icon in taskbar notification area when connected is missing in windows 7

Tags: icons, network-adapter, notification-area

Please see the picture below , 
this is on my network adapters properties :

[image]

where is the General Tab In this Network adapter ?

Also, I couldn't find that check box for Display Network Icon on the Taskbar? Where can I find it?

Is something wrong with my new installation of windows 7?

The link below is for windows xp, but I couldn't find anything for windows 7!

[How Display Network Icon on the Taskbar in windows xp](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/hnw_dc_show_icon.mspx?mfr=true)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The feature, check box for `Show icon in task notification area when connected`, you refer to has been removed since Vista per Microsoft Support Engineer (see below).

#### How can I show the network icon in the task bar like in windows XP - Microsoft TechNet

> This feature has been removed since Windows Vista. We have reported similar feature requests to our product team. Thank you for your understanding. - *([Source](http://bit.ly/pK2x4p))*

#### List of features removed in Windows Vista - Wikipedia

> A single icon in the notification area (system tray) represents network connectivity through all network adapters and/or internet gateways, whether wired or wireless and for all different types of connections. It is not possible to set individual connection status icons on the taskbar or hide some or all network icons altogether. *([Source](http://bit.ly/oYHFlf))*

Comment: thanks for answer / but some days ago i had my both network icons in system tray and i don't know what did i do about that before installing windows 7 again / i certain about that , because that network was a home network and was became enable/disable when the other pc was became on or off / however is there any trick (such as registry) for solving this issue ? also plz tell me about your network cards properties / i think my windows 7 has loses something ... am i right?

Comment: would you plz introduce some 3rd softwares about this purpose !

Comment: Let me do some more research. I'll update my answer if I find something.

Comment: I looked many places for a program that will do this for you. However, I found none. As my answer says above, the feature as been removed. Now there is just one icon that shows all network connections. I have tested this by plugging my my hardline while have 2 wireless connections enable at the same time.

Answer (score 4):

In windows 7 the notification icons are configured from Control Panel > Notification area icons, maybe your configuration is not showing the network icon nor notifications.

There is an [official page of M$ for Windows 7](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Change-how-icons-appear-in-the-notification-area)

hope it works!

Comment: thanks for answer / i checked that / but there is no separate property for each network adapter / i have 3 network adapters and i want to show all of their icons in system tray / would u plz tell me that is your network adapter properties like that picture or not ?

Comment: mine it's like yours, no checkbox for each connection as in xp